# Calculate Percent of Range of Numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

If I have a range from $-4$ to $4$, how can I figure out what $60\%$ of that range is?  Pictorially:
[image: 60 Percent of Range]

I'm looking for $x$ such that the distance from $-4$ to $x$ is $60\%$ of the distance from $-4$ to $4$.  How can I find such an $x$?

Comment: $8 \times 0.6~$

Comment: What's $60\%$ of $8$?

Comment: 60% of 8 is 4.8, but my top range can only be 4 so that can't be right?

Comment: perhaps I'm not phrasing the question right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want to know what the *entire* range is.  That is simply: $$\text{range} = \text{big number} - \text{small number} = 4-(-4) = 8$$

Then, we want sixty percent ***of*** the range.  In many word problems, one may replace the word *of* with multiplication.  That is, we're first looking for $(60\%)\times(\text{range})$.  Recall that $60\%= 0.60$, and the rest should be straightforward.

The above tells us the distance from $-4$ to $x$.  To find $x$, then, we simply add that distance to $-4$.

Comment: 60% of 8 is 4.8, but my top range can only be 4 at max so that can't be right? Perhaps I'm not phrasing the question right

Comment: @MobileMon, If you are looking for 60% of an interval, what should you do now?

Comment: @AlexSilva subtract 4 from 4.8? Leaving us at .8?

Comment: @MobileMon, that's it.